# getting 'top' and 'right' position based on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with the drop down menu that was being cut when it is opened on the last line. To fix this, I've figured out a way to detach the drop-down menu from the parent divider, and then position the drop-down menu by passing the top and right values.

I do not know how to get the value of where it should open, which should be just below the button that triggered the dropdown.

[Here a JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/y03yxd2q/21/)

```
(function() {
  var dropdownMenu;
  console.log($(window).width());
  $(window).on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {     
    dropdownMenu = $(e.target).find('.dropdown-menu');
    $('body').append(dropdownMenu.detach());          
    dropdownMenu.css('display', 'block');
    dropdownMenu.css('position', 'fixed');
    dropdownMenu.css('top', '440px');
    dropdownMenu.css('right', '100px')
  });                                                   
  $(window).on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {        
    $(e.target).append(dropdownMenu.detach());        
    dropdownMenu.hide();                              
  });                                                   
})();
```

ps.: where values are 440px and 100px should be the position relative to the button that triggered the dropdown.

Comment: every `e` (from event), have the `pageX` and `pageY` properties, that are the mouse left and top position. You can use that as a starting point

Comment: @CalvinNunes thanks for help. I tried using `pageX` and `pageY`, but they are `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is with `getBoundingClientRect()`. It will give you the x and y of the element you clicked on (as well as a few other things). I tested in both Chrome and Firefox, and it's  [cross browser compatible](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=getboundingclientRect) .

```
  $(window).on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {     
    dropdownMenu = $(e.target).find('.dropdown-menu');
    $('body').append(dropdownMenu.detach());          
    dropdownMenu.css('display', 'block');
    dropdownMenu.css('position', 'fixed');
    var topValue = e.relatedTarget.getBoundingClientRect().y
    dropdownMenu.css('top', topValue);
    var leftValue = e.relatedTarget.getBoundingClientRect().x
    dropdownMenu.css('left', leftValue);
  });
```

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/y03yxd2q/24/)

Comment: unfortunately `window.event` doesnt work in firefox =/